# Программное распределение трафика

Tags: linux, ip, tcp-ip, tunnel, ipip

Случилась такая напасть, имею 3 сервака "думающих со слабыми каналами в мир" и один с гигабитом в мир. Хочу гнать трафик на сервак с жирным каналом, там проверять IP адреса и в зависимости от проверки слать на какой то из этих трех серваков. Но, нужно сохранить IP (source и dist) и организовать это только для конкретных портов.

Какие варианты организации подобного есть?

Answer (score 1):

насколько я понимаю, примерно так:

условные обозначения:

- *host1* с внешними адресом ip1 и двумя сетевыми интерфейсами (eth0 — внешний и eth1 — локальный);
- *host2* внутри локальной сети, на который должен приходить трафик извне на адрес ip2 с одним сетевым интерфейсом.

действия:

1. на машине *host2* добавить адрес *ip2* на сетевую карту.
2. на машине *host2* дефолтным шлюзом прописать адрес интерфейса *eth1* машины *host1*.
3. на машине *host1* добавить маршрут к *ip2* через *eth1*.
4. на интерфейс *eth0* машины *host1* адрес *ip2* **не** прописывать.
5. разрешить *forwarding* пакетов на машине *host1*.
6. добавить на машине *host1* необходимые правила *netfilter*-а (адрес источника у приходящих на *eth0* и перебрасываемых на *eth1* пакетов **не** подменять).